# How to configure the sqlplus login errors?

Tags: oracle, authentication, sqlplus

### i hve a problem loging in to the oracle sqlplus

---

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoVYX.jpg)

[Sqlplus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/resZR.jpg)

Comment: What's the database version and o/s?

Comment: Looks like the database service is stuck either trying so startup or shutdown. Check the alert log to see which, and for other error messages.

Comment: It would help if you were to show the exact, full, and complete connection attempt, beginning with your invocation of sqlplus.  How are we supposed to know exactly what " tried many ways" includes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky enough and nothing is actually broken, the simplest way to try to "fix" it is to

- shutdown your computer (presuming that database is installed on it) and
- start it up (presuming, again, that database you use will also automatically start up).

  - Wait for a while, it may take time.
- if it is MS Windows, check **services**; you should see something like this:

  [image]
- if the database is up, you should now be able to connect to it and unlock the HR user:

  ```
  C:\>sqlplus sys as sysdba

  SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Pon Kol 2 22:38:22 2021

  Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

  Enter password:

  Connected to:
  Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

  SQL> alter user hr account unlock;

  User altered.

  SQL>
  ```

---

If it is not that simple, then you should describe it again, providing some/much more details of what you have, what you did, ... everything.